# Get source TFS Server in TFS Build Definition

Tags: tfs

Is there a variable or property which is acccesible in the TFS Build Workflow that contains the source TFS Server and collection for the TeamProject?  I can see the TeamProject name hanging off of the BuildDefinition object, but what I am really looking for the is source uri for it.

IE: `http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how:

> BuildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.Uri.AbsoluteUri

Comment: As an FYI, if you are modifying your build template you will need to add a reference to: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client